# It is possible to change USB device class from mass storage to serial?

Tags: linux, windows, webusb, usb-mass-storage

I have a USB device, that works as a mass storage device.
The access is blocked on Chrome browser through WebUSB because it's a mass storage device.
The device also supports raw access as a block device.

So my idea was to change the device class.
How can I do this on Linux (with a udev rule?) and Windows 10?
Thank you

Comment: Mass storage device IS a block device. If a device has no CDC configuration, how can you force it to appear?

Comment: I tried using WebUSB once by installing a WinUSB driver for that device, but Chrome blocks access based on the USB descriptor, so there's no way around it AFAIK. Google themselves use a Chrome extension (Chromebook Recover Utlity) to flash ChromeOS to a mass storage device, so maybe that's one possibility?

They did consider at one stage to have an allow list as an enterprise policy, but then switched to an alternative approach: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1056757 I don't know if they ever said what this alternative approach was.

Comment: Low-level access to mass storage devices is a security and privacy concern because it allows a site to bypass the operating system's permission model for file access. The current plan is to support unrestricted WebUSB access only in Isolated Web Apps: https://github.com/WICG/webusb/blob/main/unrestricted-usb-explainer.md

Comment: I see the Chromium issue I referred to above has now been updated so that the linked issue to using Isolated Web Apps for unrestricted WebUSB access is now publicly available. Nice! :)